# cant print to console anymore ROS_INFO or std::cout

Tags: ros, ros-info, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Whenever I try publishing an output to the command line in my node I receive the following error:

"Attempt to set a screen on a child window."

I couldnt find any help on my particular problem online. The strange thing is that the output to the console worked fine with either ROS_INFO or std::cout some weeks back.
I didnt use it since and cant think about any things I have changed which causes this error. Maybe someone on here knows.
The output on the console of the ros node on the start up is this:

```
Waiting 0.2 seconds after advertising topics...[ INFO] [1519836743.658042843]: rviz version 1.12.15
[ INFO] [1519836743.658088066]: compiled against Qt version 5.5.1
[ INFO] [1519836743.658098402]: compiled against OGRE version 1.9.0 (Ghadamon)
 done.
Hit space to toggle paused, or 's' to step.
[ INFO] [1519836743.931421874]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED00000 / 203.588303               
[ INFO] [1519836743.931532108]: OpenGl version: 3 (GLSL 1.3).
0x124a800 void QWindowPrivate::setTopLevelScreen(QScreen*, bool) ( QScreen(0x76ebf0) ): Attempt to set a screen on a child window.
0x124c4b0 void QWindowPrivate::setTopLevelScreen(QScreen*, bool) ( QScreen(0x76ebf0) ): Attempt to set a screen on a child window.
0x124c690 void QWindowPrivate::setTopLevelScreen(QScreen*, bool) ( QScreen(0x76ebf0) ): Attempt to set a screen on a child window.
0x1418700 void QWindowPrivate::setTopLevelScreen(QScreen*, bool) ( QScreen(0x76ebf0) ): Attempt to set a screen on a child window.`
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283980/cant-print-to-console-anymore-ros_info-or-std::cout/) by [Peter1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33821/peter1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2018-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They have similar issues in [here](https://github.com/c42f/displaz/issues/135) and apparently is related with qt4 that needs migration into qt5. This is specially relevant because from indigo to kinetic thats precisely one of the changes (qt4 was deprecated in favor of qt5).

---

Originally posted by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) with karma: 831 on 2018-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0